# sketch graph and find volume

Tags: calculus

Sketch the region below the graph of the curve,
y(x)= 1/ (x−1)

and above the x−axis for x ∈ [2, 4].
Now compute the volume of the solid obtained by rotating this region about the x−axis.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solid of revolution about the $x$-axis as depicted below:

[image: solid of revolution]

Cross-sections of the solid taken perpendicular to the axis of revolution are circles with $A=\pi r^2=\pi y^2=\dfrac{\pi}{(x-1)^2}$

So $V=\displaystyle\int_2^4A(x)\,dx=\displaystyle\int_2^4\dfrac{\pi}{(1-x)^2}\,dx=\left[-\dfrac{\pi}{x-1}\right]_2^4=\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{3}=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$.

See a Desmos animation at [this link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5vcdqckyd4).

Just drag the value of $t$ in the animation to move the gray cross-section.

Comment: Thank you sooooooo muchhhhhhhh 

Comment: You are welcome. Be sure to check the arrow to the left of my answer.